# Confused about the baggage fee for different airlines

Tags: luggage, airlines, fees-and-charges

I purchased a ticket from orbitz.com. It's an Iberia flight from Casablanca, Morocco to Charlotte, NC with a layover in Madrid. Although it's an Iberia ticket, the first flight is operated by Royal Air Maroc and the the second one by US Airways.

I would like to add two items of baggage (I'm moving to NC), but I don't know which company fee will apply. I called Iberia here in Morocco and they said they don't know. I contacted orbitz and one operator told me that it would be Royal Air Maroc's and US Airways fees (BOTH), another one that it would be Royal Air Maroc's.

Please help me figure out how much I will have to pay by telling me which airlines baggage fee is applicable.

Answer (score 2):

typically in such cases on each leg of the flight the restrictions and fees of the company operating that leg will apply.
So most likely you're going to have to pay RAM for the leg to Madrid, and US for the leg from Madrid to Charlotte.
You're also going to have to comply with size and weight restrictions for each airline separate.
Especially the latter has caught more than a few people by surprise when they end up having to pay extra for baggage when crosschecking it onto an airline with lower allowances they didn't take into account when packing.

Of course being a combined ticket sold by Iberia, depending on the terms of the contract, you might have to pay Iberia fees for each leg, but you'd still be subject to the size and weight restrictions of RAM and US, not Iberia.
Don't call Orbitz, call Iberia. They're the ones who should know, as they're the ones you have a contract with.